# Beamer customization - itemize not changing color

Tags: beamer, formatting, itemize

I am trying to recreate [this](http://www.phys.chuo-u.ac.jp/labs/inami/seminarfile/2012/5Hikida.pdf) presentation in `beamer`. I finally made a proper header, but for some reason my `itemize items` won't change color. Here is a code sample

```
%&latex

\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},hyperref={breaklinks=true}%,mathserif
,10pt]{beamer} 


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{time}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{siva}{RGB}{147,162,153}
\definecolor{crvena}{RGB}{210,83,60}
\definecolor{ljub}{RGB}{87,87,110}
\definecolor{flatblue}{RGB}{0, 82, 156}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}


\usecolortheme[named=flatblue]{structure} 
\usetheme{Rochester}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor*{itemize items}{bg=siva,fg=siva}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\sffamily, shape=\upshape}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=red}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=headline}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{\hspace*{-0.5cm}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[white,line width=0.12cm] (-1,6) -- (14,6);
        \draw[siva,line width=0.51cm] (-1,6.31) -- (14,6.31);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}


\begin{document}



\begingroup
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=crvena}
\begin{frame}
\vspace{2.6 cm}
\Huge\textcolor{white}{1. INTRODUCTION}\vspace*{-0.3cm}
\hspace*{-0.2cm}\textcolor{white}{\rule{1.\textwidth}{0.025cm}}
\Large {\textcolor{white}{This is where a little intro text goes}}
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: can you please answer your own question after the time limit passes such that it doesn't stay in the unanswered question list?

Comment: Sorry, I just found the answer immediately, and originally I'd vote to delete the question, but it's not possible here :\

Comment: @dingo_d Your question is not only for you ;-). It is meant to help others with a similar problem too. Hence please put a self answer intead of deleting it :-)

Comment: Well, I put the answer in the edit, I hope it will benefit others somehow :)

Answer (score 2):

The OP found the solution himself; here it is (I post it in his behalf as CW):

```
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=siva}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=siva}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=siva}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
```